# How to use a block of node js code for a second case?

Tags: javascript, node.js

First of all, let me be more specific. I have a nodemailer code setup for Contact page in my website and it works just fine. However, I have another page, Services, which I have another form and want to use that previous setup code for this page as well so I'm able to send submitted infos as an email. I tried to make another file and pasted the same code but named the variables such `app2`, `transporter2` and so on. But it won't work. I'm a beginner in nodejs development so I need help. What is the best way to achieve that?

By the way; Contact, Services pages and app.js (nodejs code) files are in the root folder.

Node js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  const output = `
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    </ul>
  `;

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    port: 25,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: 'email', // senders email
        pass: 'password' // senders password
    },
    tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false
    }
  });

  // setup email data with raw html
  let mailOptions = {
      from: '"xyz" <xyz@info.com>', // sender address
      to: req.body.email, // receiver or receivers
      subject: 'xyz', // Subject line
      html: output // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

      res.render('contact', {msg:'Your contact message has successfully sent to us.'});
  });
  });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

Comment: I do not understand your problem. You serve 2 pages that should both send emails, and you only succeed sending emails with 1 page?

Comment: I already can send email for one page and have the code setup for it. But I wanted to use this code to be able to send emails in another page so this is what I try to solve @RaphaMex

Comment: Sounds like you are asking how to write reusable code?? Why don't you just define a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, you create a module. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

```
//yourModule.js
const sendMail = (email, output) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  //your code to send mail.
  //resolve the promise
})

module.exports { sendMail }
```

Then you include it wherever you need:

```
const emailModule = require('myModuleName');

emailModule.sendMail('some@mail.com', output).then(() => {
  //whatever
}).catch(catchErrFn)
```